# Going through a textbook and I seem to have a difficulty with the return function when writing my own excersie

Tags: python, python-2.7, return

```
year = raw_input("What year were you born?: ")

def age_calc(f):
    print "To calculate your age, I will subtract the current year from your birthyear!"
    return 2011 - "%d" % (f)

age = age_calc(year)

print age
```

This is the code excersise that I wrote, and this is the error that I can't get around...

```
File "agecalc.py", line 7, in <module>
  age = age_calc(year)
File "agecalc.py", line 5, in age_calc
  return 2011 - "%d" % (f)
TypeError: int argument required
```

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. You can't subtract a string from an `int`. What do you think `"%d" % (f)` does?

Comment: When I was doing research, I learned that %d represents a signed integer, can you elaborate on why that is still bad? Is it because anything within quotes automatically becomes a string?

Comment: year is a string, so f is too. make it : `int(f)` or `%s`

Comment: You are correct; `'%d'` represents a signed integer _in a format string_. When you use `%` to combine a string and a value (like `'%d' % 5`), the value is converted into a string using the format specification as a guide, and inserted into the format string where the format specification appears. So the resulting value is a string. If you want to convert a string to an int, use `int()`.

Comment: So I could do something like:    
    def age_calc(int(f));
    return 2011 - "%d" % (f)....

Would that work?

Comment: Well, it's hard to tell what you've written since multiline code is hard to read in comments. But the answer is probably no, because you're still subtracting `"%d"`, a string, from `2011`, a number. Forget all about `%d` for now; it's not useful for this problem. It's useful for things like this: `print 'You are %d years old' % 5`, which converts `5` into a string and inserts it into the format string, producing the string `'You are 5 years old'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are mixing up strings and numbers in the computation. In the original code

```
return 2011 - "%d" % (f)
         ^      ^
         |      |
     integer   string
```

a string is being subtracted form an integer - which causes the error message: `TypeError: int argument required`

Here's an improved version:

```
def age_calc(yr):
    print "To calculate your age, I will subtract the current year from your birthyear!"
    return 2011 - yr

year = int(raw_input("What year were you born?: ")) # convert string to int
age = age_calc(year)

print age
```

Notice that I convert the user input from a string to an `int` where you prompt for input, and then do all the calculations with numbers rather than strings and numbers.

In the original code you were passing a string to `age_calc()` and then using it to subtract from the number 2011. Now you are sending an integer to `age_calc()` and there's no problem subtracting an integer from another integer (2011).

I also used a slightly more descriptive identifier for your function argument `yr` rather than `f`.

Answer (score 1):

`%d` wants `f` to be an integer, while in your case it's a string.

```
`return 2011 - "%d" % (f)`
```

also in `2011 - "%d" % (f)` you're trying to subtract a string from a number, which is also wrong.

**working version of your code:**

```
year = int(raw_input("What year were you born?: ")) #convert to int using int()

def age_calc(f):
    print "To calculate your age, I will subtract the current year from your birthyear!"
    return 2011 - f # or return "{0}".format(2011-f)  if you want to return a string 

age = age_calc(year)

print age
```